# Looking up a map using a key method, manages to find the key in the map. How?

Tags: java, maps, equality, treemap

I have a `TreeMap` containing a mapping of `StockItem` values:

```java
private final Map<StockItem, Integer> list;
```

I am using a method to look up values within this map by generating a key which returns a type of `StockItem`.

Here is the method:

```java
public static StockItem makeKey(String name, double price, int quantityStock){
    return new StockItem(name,price,quantityStock);
}
```

The code works fine and lookups work well, my question is how exactly is it possible for this to happen? The `makeKey` method returns a completely new object which contains the exact same data that may be contained in a list. Does it go through each iteration then call `.equals` to compare each object?

Here is the `StockItem` class:

```java
public class StockItem implements Comparable<StockItem> {
    private final String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private int reserveItems = 0;

    public StockItem(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        quantity = 0;
    }

    public StockItem(String name, double price, int quantityStock) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        quantity = quantityStock;

    }

    public void reserveItem(int amountReserved){
        this.reserveItems = amountReserved + this.reserveItems;
    }

    public void unReserveItem(int unreserve){
        reserveItems = reserveItems - unreserve;
    }

    public int getReservedAmount(){
        return reserveItems;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int quantityInStock() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void adjustStock(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = this.quantity + quantity - this.reserveItems;
    }

    public final void setPrice(double price) {
        if (price > 0.0)
        this.price = price;
    }

    public static StockItem MakeKey(String name, double price, int quantityStock){
        return new StockItem(name,price,quantityStock);
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(StockItem o) {
        if (this == o){
            return 0;
        }

        if (o != null){
            return this.name.compareTo(o.getName());
        }

        throw new NullPointerException();
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "Item Name: " + this.name + " Item Price: " + this.price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the StockItem code.

Comment: It only works *if* the actual map is a `TreeMap` (not shown in code), in which case the lookup is by the name value of the `StockItem`, as implemented by the `compareTo()` method of the `Comparable` interface, which is what a `TreeMap` uses. If the map is a `HashMap`, the lookup would fail, since the `StockItem` class doesn't implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`. See javadoc of [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for description of how they work.

Comment: @4castle TreeMap

Comment: @Andreas okay, so in the HashMap if I did the same thing but used the equals and hashcode would this work too?

Comment: @JordanDixon Yes.

Answer (score 0):

A `TreeMap` without a `Comparator` such as in your example does its lookups based on whether its objects' `compareTo` methods deem the items as being equal:

> a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal.

Since `StockItem`'s `compareTo` returns true whenever the `name` values are equal, and since the "key" items contain the `name` value, the map lookup by key returns the corresponding item as the "key" object is considered equal to the whole object by the map.

The answer to your question of how it works and whether it iterates through each object can be determined from `TreeMap`'s [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation.
> [...]
> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the `containsKey`, `get`, `put` and `remove` operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's *Introduction to Algorithms*.

As stated, the lookups are performed using a [red–black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).  The details of how that works are outside the scope of what can be reasonably fit in this answer.  However, the fact that the `get` method is defined to be log(n) [time cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) tells us that it's not iterating over all elements in the list, as an iteration over all elements would be a more expensive n time cost.